# Showing minimizer satisfies equality of general norm.

Tags: analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I've been doing some self-studying on convex optimization recently.  I'm trying to prove the fact that: $$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} y \cdot x + \frac{c}{2} \lvert x \rvert^2 = \frac{-1}{2c} \lvert y \rvert_*^2,$$ where $c>0$, $y \in R^n$, and  || denotes a general norm and $||_*$ denotes the dual norm.

I've been trying to prove this fact using results about strong convexity and L-smoothness but to no avail - could anyone help me prove it?

Thanks!

Comment: See Rockafellar's *Convex Analysis*, Chapter 15.

Answer (score 0):

By (a generalized) Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
\begin{align*}
| y^T x | \le \|y\|_* \|x\|.
\end{align*}
So $y^T x \ge -\|y\|_* \|x\|$. Then
\begin{align*}
y^T x + \frac{c}{2} \|x\|^2 \ge -\|y\|_* \|x\| + \frac{c}{2}\|x\|^2.
\end{align*}
The right-hand side can be minimized by letting $\|x\| = \frac{\|y\|_*}{c}$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
  y^T x + \frac{c}{2} \|x\|^2 \ge -\|y\|_* \|x\| + \frac{c}{2}\|x\|^2 \ge -\frac{1}{2c}\|y\|_*^2.
\end{align*}
If the equality is tight, then we get what needed. It suffices to show there exists a $x$ with $\|x\| = \|y\|_*/c$ such that $y^T x = -\|y\|_*\|x\|$. This is indeed the case. By definition of dual norm, we have $\|y\|_* = \sup_{\|x\| =1} y^T x $. Since $\{x : \|x\|=1\}$ is compact and $y^Tx$ is linear, then the sup is indeed a max. So there is some $\|\bar{x}\| = 1$ such that $\|y\|_* = y^T \bar{x}$. Now take $\tilde{x} = -\frac {\bar{x}} {c /\|y\|_*}$, then we have $\|\tilde{x}\| = \|y\|_*/c$ and $y^T \tilde{x} = -\frac{\|y\|_*}{c} y^T \bar{x} = -\|y\|_* \|\tilde{x}\|$. This shows the equality can be achieved.

Comment: I thought Hölder's inequality is for $p$-norms only?

Comment: @max_zorn: You are right. Thanks for pointing out. I would delete the H\"{o}lder part. But I think the argument is still correct.